# Convergence acceleration using rational approximation

Tags: convergence-divergence, approximation, approximation-theory, convergence-acceleration

How Pade Approximations accelerate the convergence of series??? Here I don't mean only the Pade Approximations, just in general how do the rational approximations contribute to series convergence accelerationg problem???